# Numpy array of multiple indices replace with a different matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of 2d indices.

```
indices = [[2,4], [6,77], [102,554]]
```

Now, I have a different 4-dimensional array, arr, and I want to only extract an array (it is an array, since it is 4-dimensional) with corresponding index in the indices array. It is equivalent to the following code.

```
for i in range(len(indices)):
    output[i] = arr[indices[i][0], indices[i][1]]
```

However, I realized that using explicit for-loop yields a slow result. Is there any built-in numpy API that I can utilized? At this point, I tried using np.choose, np.put, np.take, but did not succeed to yield what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to index into the first two axes with the two columns from indices (thinking of it as an array).

Thus, simply convert to array and index, like so -

```
indices_arr = np.array(indices)
out = arr[indices_arr[:,0], indices_arr[:,1]]
```

Or we could extract those directly without converting to array and  then index -

```
d0,d1 = [i[0] for i in indices], [i[1] for i in indices]
out = arr[d0,d1]
```

Another way to extract the elements would be with conversion to tuple, like so -

```
out = arr[tuple(indices_arr.T)]
```

If `indices` is already an array, skip the conversion process and use `indices` in places where we had `indices_arr`.

Comment: Is the first method faster than using the explicit for-loop?

Comment: @AverageAlgorithmGuy If you already have `indices` as an array, I would go with the first approach, else go with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the take function of numpy arrays. Your code should be something like:

```
outputarray= np.take(arr,indices)
```

Comment: From [the numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html): "If indices is not one dimensional, the output also has these dimensions." That means it will return `[[arr[indices[0][0]], arr[indices[0][1]], ...], [arr[indices[1][0]], arr[indices[1][1]], ...], ...]`